# ERROR In Importing Mysql DB dump On AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I took Mysql DB  dump from  one RDS server and trying to restore in another RDS server.While importing the complete DB i am getting below error.

```
ERROR 1419 (HY000) at line 2447: You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)
```

After that i changed the  parameter to 1 applied then rebooted the server.

Again i tried importing the dump i got below error.

```
ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 2447: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation.
```

Please help on this.

Comment: user which is trying to import does not have sufficient privileges. try importing as root

Comment: Thanks. i am trying with one user who is having complete rights.its one copy of root user.

Comment: he does not have SUPER priv, that's why it's not working. root has that by default

Comment: FYI

| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'mypassword' WITH GRANT OPTION |

Comment: and there is no SUPER in that list is there ?

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mydatabase`.* TO 'myuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36401/discussion-between-krishna-chandra-and-hrvoje-spoljar).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my tutorial on [importing Wordpress sites into AWS/RDS](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-3-migrating-wordpress-sites-into-aws/), it covers the basics in a fairly easy to understand way.

You need to create your user with the appropriate privileges.

```
CREATE USER '***user'@'***PRIVATE_IP_HERE' IDENTIFIED BY '***INSERT_PASSWORD_HERE';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON INSERT_DATABASE_NAME_HERE.* TO '***user'@'PRIVATE_IP_HERE' IDENTIFIED BY 'INSERT_PASSWORD_HERE';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I never worked out why a user and a grant both need a password. I just set them the same.

Comment: Error remains same...First error.

Comment: Unfortunately you're going to have to do some problem solving yourself. Work out why you don't have the right privileges using the MySQL command line program.